# mongodb insert document with just id, or do nothing

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a database of web domains, where the data is like this:

```
{"_id": "es.wikipedia.org"}
{"_id": "en.wikipedia.org"}
```

And I want to (try to) insert domains which may already be in the collection like "stackoverflow.com" or "es.wikipedia.org", so if the document is not in the database, insert it, but if it is, then just skip and do nothing. But I cannot do it in one operation. If I go with

```
 collection.insert(new Document("_id", "es.wikipedia.org"));
```

it fails with an exception if the document already exists in the collection. And if I try to go with an update, like this:

```
 collection.updateOne(new Document("_id", "es.wikipedia.org"), new Document("$set", new Document()), new UpdateOptions().upsert(true));
```

it fails because the `$set` field is empty. But it is just a list, it does not have (at the moment) any more fields than "_id". Is there a way to do this? Am I making a mistake?

Comment: `_id` should be unique in all the collection

Comment: @charliebrownie I have read my question and I didn't make myself clear. Let me correct that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find out whether the record with that id exists DB or not then your can do your further processing.

```
var res = db.user.find({"_id": "es.wikipedia.org"});

if(res.length()){

  db.user.insert({"_id": "es.wikipedia.org"});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a MongoDB version from 2.6 or newer, use the insert() method with the ordered option set to false. Setting the option to false will result in exceptions for attempts to insert a document with a duplicate key, but the remaining documents to be inserted will continue to be processed (and inserted, if they are not duplicates.) See this article:

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/

...and pay attention to the section on unordered inserts.

If you are using MongoDB version 3.2.x, you can also use the insertMany() method to perform unordered inserts of an array of documents. Setting the ordered option to false will result exceptions for attempts to insert documents with duplicate keys, but all the new documents in the array will be added to the collection. See this article:

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/

...and pay attention to the section on unordered inserts.